# how to create a spider chart pointing towards single point in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to create aan html object, like below

---

[image]

---

like this picture in HTML, while hovering display pictures or something.
I just need something like this which contains child texts pointing towards parents texts

I searched a lot, but I don't its name.
How to search it or any examples?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Jop/pen/rjdMVm

Comment: If you want to use a js library. You can use gojs library.

This link for your requirement https://gojs.net/latest/samples/pageFlow.html